# Android: Grouping apps according to their Action(Functionalities)

Tags: android, android-intent, package-managers

I am trying to group up Apk's that are installed in our android phone based on their functionalities.. E.G. Grouping browser apps like Internet, chrome, Dolphin Browser etc.. Specifically i need to group Email clients, Browser apps and Messaing apps..

I had already did a R&D and i found **pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,pkgManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER),** in which intent is pointing the

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

which list the email clients but still it is not listing all the mail client. i couldnt get **K9-Mail** and some other third party mail client in the list which pkgManager.queryIntentActivities returns.

Plz help in to group E-mail client, Browser and Messaging apps

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard `Intent` structures that are guaranteed to uniquely identify "E-mail client, Browser and Messaging apps", even assuming that there is a universal *human* definition of those terms. You will have to do this grouping by hand for your pre-installed apps using whatever criteria you choose to represent such apps.

Comment: i couldnt get the point "You will have to do this grouping by hand for your pre-installed apps using whatever criteria you choose to represent such apps"

Comment: @Deepak: Look at the first app. Decide for yourself what category it belongs in, if any. Write that down somewhere. Then look at the second app. Decide for yourself what category it belongs in, if any. Write that down somewhere. Then look at the third app. Decide for yourself what category it belongs in, if any. Write that down somewhere. Then look at the fourth app. Decide for yourself what category it belongs in, if any. Write that down somewhere. Continue this process for all of your pre-installed apps, then use the resulting information as you see fit.